# What is the term for adding benign code/behavior to malware to evade antiviruses?

Tags: malware, antimalware, machine-learning

Some malware authors add benign code/behavior to their malware just to throw off antiviruses and IDSs which employ machine learning to detect malware. There is a name for this technique (and even a Wikipedia page somewhere) but I can't seem to figure out what it is or find it on Google.

Comment: Do you mean *"mimicry"*, i.e. looking like something good while being bad?

Comment: It is mimicking for sure, but that's not the term. Essentially the idea is to stuff a malware with a bunch of code from well-known benign programs.

Comment: I know what you mean, like in [this bypass of Cylance](https://skylightcyber.com/2019/07/18/cylance-i-kill-you/). But I'm not sure that there is a special term focusing on what you mean and I cannot find any such term in this post either.

Comment: I think you mean [polymorphic malware](https://digitalguardian.com/blog/what-polymorphic-malware-definition-and-best-practices-defending-against-polymorphic-malware). There are open source frameworks for this like [Veil](https://www.veil-framework.com/)

Comment: @SteffenUllrich That is exactly what I was thinking of! I could have sworn I saw a Wiki page on that technique and it was given some interesting name I was hoping I could search up, but I suppose if articles like the one you linked don't use the term, then maybe it hasn't taken hold.

Comment: @paj28 I know its not polymorphism per se. Polymorphic decryptors don't necessarily patch in code from other programs, which is the technique I am looking for. Thanks for bringing up Veil though, that'll be something interesting to look into

Answer (score 1):

I think the technique is called obfuscation using "dead code insertion" where you add routines that don't perform any function to throw off AV static and dynamic analysis.
I read it [here](https://www.andreafortuna.org/2018/02/12/malware-hiding-and-evasion-techniques/)
Also this wiki leaks [paper](https://wikileaks.org/ciav7p1/cms/files/BypassAVDynamics.pdf) shows experiments with AV that use techniques of adding functions that dont do anything but bypass AV dynamic analysis

Comment: Would you please add some references where this term is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Malware hiding within an app with a benign purpose is typically called a Trojan, after the famous story of the [Trojan Horse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse).